# Is CABasicAnimation practice different for UI objects and CALayers?

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I was just wondering if this is the correct way to animate a CALayer with a CABasicAnimation.

On Stack Overflow I have been taught how to animate UI objects by setting a new position before running a CABasicAnimation:

**Animating a UI Object Example**

```
gameTypeControl.center = CGPointMake(gameTypeControl.center.x, -slidingUpValue/2);
CABasicAnimation *removeGameTypeControl = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
[removeGameTypeControl setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slidingUpValue]];
[removeGameTypeControl setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
[removeGameTypeControl setDuration:1.0];
[removeGameTypeControl setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.8 :-0.8 :1.0 :1.0]];
[[gameTypeControl layer] addAnimation:removeGameTypeControl forKey:@"removeGameTypeControl"];
```

Now I've been tried this method on a CALayer but it seems to work differently. For me to get the same result. I have the set the ToValue to the new y position instead of using the value 0 like I've done with my UI object animations.

**Animating a CALayer Example**

```
serveBlock2.position = CGPointMake((screenBounds.size.height/4)*3, -screenBounds.size.width/2);
CABasicAnimation *updateCurrentServe2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
updateCurrentServe2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slidingUpValue/2];
[updateCurrentServe2 setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-screenBounds.size.width/2]];
[updateCurrentServe2 setDuration:1.0];
[serveBlock2 addAnimation:updateCurrentServe2 forKey:@"serveBlock2 updateCurrentServe2"];
```

Is this correct? Am I doing this right?

Comment: `serveBlock2` is a CALayer. `[gameTypeControl layer]` is a CALayer. The examples are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if `serveBlock2` is not a view's immediately underlying layer, setting its `position`, as you do in the first line of the second example, starts a different animation (an implicit animation). The way to prevent that is by turning off implicit animations. Thus this example [from my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_using_a_cabasicanimation):

```
CompassLayer* c = (CompassLayer*)self.compass.layer;
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]; // <=== this is important
c.arrow.transform = CATransform3DRotate(c.arrow.transform, M_PI/4.0, 0, 0, 1);
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
anim.duration = 0.8;
[c.arrow addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

That way, I don't have to have a `fromValue` or a `toValue`! The old value and the new value are known automatically from the presentation layer and the model layer.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate more on how the old and new values can be known automatically from the presentation layer and the model layer in your example above? If I understand correctly: by using `setDisableAction:YES` we prevent `c` from being animated implicitly so the transform doesn't take place until you call `CABasicAnimation`, am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: The animation takes place much later, after the end of the current CATransaction.

Comment: @Unheilig the transform (or any other change) takes place now. But the user doesn't see it because the presentation layer doesn't start to move until the animation begins, which is later. See [my explanation](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_drawing_animation_and_threading) of when animation runs and how it works.